# Pyspark streaming. RDD to DF and reuse this DF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have installed Spark 2.1.0 and have connected Kafka to Spark Streaming. I use python 3.5.
By default, so far as I understand Spark Streaming I work with RDDs, but I want to work with DataFrames. So I convert RDD to DF, however I can't use it. Obviously, foreachRDD action returns None.

I'm able to print DataFrame out, but not to use it for further computations.

**The question:**

What do I miss?

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "10.0.26.44:2183",
                                      'spark-streaming', {'topic': 1})


pipelined_rdd = kafkaStream.filter(lambda v: is_valid_json(v))
pipelined_rdd = pipelined_rdd.map(lambda v: parse_events(v))

pipelined_rdd.foreachRDD(convert_to_df)
```

where function `convert_to_df()`

```
def convert_to_df(rdd):
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("record_timestamp", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("event_timestamp", StringType(), True)])
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema = schema)
    df.show(10)
    #return df
```

Comment: _but I want to work with DataFrames_ - Use [structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)?

Comment: Firstly, I want to solve this issue. Secondly, I receive 
 with Dstreams `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka.`. Thirdly, streaming data is unfortunately dirty. So I need to clean it up before inferring a schema. @user8371915

Comment: "I'm able to print DataFrame out, but not to use it for further computations." Generally .foreachRDD is used as last step (action) to give the data to an external ouput after all computations. I would suggest to clean all the data using map or similar fucntions on dStream and convert to dataframe using foreachRDD as last step and do all the computations in it and dump it.

Comment: Refer to this link https://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2017/10/15/using-spark-sql-and-spark-streaming-together/